# Imagen por default en IformFile ,asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

como puedo settear una imagen por defecto en mi controler? Cuando el user no sube una imagen que automaticamente ponga una default:
Si no tienen imagen desde el controller de create, se mete una default o desde la db o desde una imagen sin base64.

```
Model:
public IFormFile Foto { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Person person,IFormFile file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (person.BirthYear == 0)
            {
                person.BirthYear = person.BirthDate.Value.Year;
            }


            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                var ImagePath = @"/images2/";
                var uploadPath = _env.WebRootPath + ImagePath;

                if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
                }
                var uniqFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(uniqFileName + "." + file.FileName.Split(".")[1].ToLower());
                string fullPath = uploadPath + filename;

                ImagePath = ImagePath + @"\";
                var filePath = @".." + Path.Combine(ImagePath, filename);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {

                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                    person.ImagePath = s;
                }
                _context.Add(person);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                ViewData["FileLocation"] = filePath;

            }
            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "People", action = "Details", id = person.PersonId });
        }


        return View(person);
    }
```

Se que algo sencillo pero no consigo dar con la tecla, se agradece por la ayuda C:

Answer (score 0):

Intenta preguntando si el parametro file es null. Si es null entonces buscas una imagen que tendras en la carpeta `App_Data` y le agregas esa por defecto:

```
if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
{
  //...
}
else{
  // como file es null, entonces guardamos una imagen que sera la de por defecto
  var defaultFile =  Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/default_profiler_png.png");
 // haces lo que tengas que hacer con la imagen
}
```

Esto suponiendo que tienes una imagen en la carpeta App_Data llamada `default_profiler_photo.png`.